# Why arguments of threads sometimes confuse in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, pycharm, python-multithreading

I code basic thread program :

```
import threading
```

> initialize threads

```
class OpenThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID

    def run(self):
        print thread.threadID

for tID in range(0, 5):
    thread = OpenThread(tID)
    thread.start()
```

and last 5 outputs of trying are here:

```
####try 1 
0
1
2
3
4

####try 2 
0
1
 2
3
4

####try 3 
0
2
23

4



####try 4 

0
1
2
3
 4

####try 5 

0
1
3
 34
```

I use PyCharm as IDE.
I don't understand why there are space character and why more thread argument get same value

Answer (score 0):

Please read more about  **Print Thread Safe**.

The issue is that python uses seperate opcodes for the NEWLINE printing and the printing of the object itself. The easiest solution is probably to just use an explicit sys.stdout.write with an explicit newline. Or  use a lock and rebind "print"! Or use the logging system! .

```
from __future__ import print_function
print = lambda x: sys.stdout.write("%s\n" % x)
```

or

```
import threading
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger('thread-safe')

class OpenThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID

    def run(self):
        logger.debug(thread.threadID)

for tID in range(0, 5):
    thread = OpenThread(tID)
    thread.start()
```

print in python3 is safe.

Comment: would print thread unsafety corrupt the output too? it seems the numbers in the output are not correct too, without considering the new lines.

Comment: @all3g I can understand newline problem, I don't care it. But I don't understand space character that show up in output and the same argument values for threads. I tried your code and threads still get same threadID values.

Comment: Please correct **thread.threadID** to **self.threadID** also.

Comment: If I add  thread.join() after thread.start(), without one of the threads finish, another thread can't be created. This make away with advantages of the multithreading and I want all threads work together.

Comment: I don't know why, but use **self.threadID** instead of **thread.threadID**, solve same value problem. But space character problem still continues.